# What is Hamming Window in Audio Analysis?

Tags: signal-processing, noise, audio

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.01778.pdf). The paper writes

> ... an input waveform of t seconds is converted into a sequence of 128-D log mel filter bank features computed with 25 ms Hamming window every 10 s. The results is 128*100t spectrogram.

My questions are:

$\bullet$ What is hamming window ?

$\bullet$ How did the authors arrive at 128*100t based on their description ?

Any help and direction to relevant reading material will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A spectrogram is a (2D) time-frequency representation of a waveform (time signal). On one axis (generally X) it represents time, on another axis (generally Y) it represents frequency. The way to generate a spectrogram is to perform a Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT), which transforms chunks of the time domain signal into the frequency domain and puts them together to get a time-frequency representation.

Now, when doing the STFT, each chunk of signal can be windowed prior to the transform to frequency domain. This is generally done to avoid problems, such as spectral leakage. These problems occur because we have a finite discrete signal, which does not allow us to have infinite frequency resolution. Wikipedia has a good overview on signals and how they affect the signal after transformed to time domain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

The Hamming Window is a specific kind of window, very commonly used in STFT.[image].

When performing the STFT, there are generally 3 very important parameters:

- Number of points in the FFT: It determines the frequency resolution of the spectrogram.
- Number of samples per chunk
- Hop size (or overlap): Normally, to avoid drastic changes between consecutive time bins in the spectrogram, the audio chunks that are used for the STFT partially overlap with the consecutive ones. This is how the authors arrived at the 128*100t spectrogram - they say they sample 25ms of signal every 10ms (hop size = 10ms) (1 second / 10ms = 100 time bins per second).